# Interval of convergance $\sum_0^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^3}*x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

$$\sum_0^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^3}*x^n$$

I have no idea how to do this. I tried to write it all out with the ratio test and I get some weird expression that doesn't make sense like

$$x * \frac{(2(n+1))!}{(n+1)!^3} * \frac{n!^3}{2n!} $$

I can't really make sense of it, I can't prove that anything is growing faster than anything else. I know that the top is growing faster with a larger factorial and x but I really don't know for sure, just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some troubles with the factorials , i try to be clear:

**Hint** :$ \ \ \ \ x \cdot  \dfrac{(2(n+1))!}{(n+1)!^3}  \dfrac{n!^3}{2n!}=x  \dfrac{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!}{(n+1)^3\cdot n!^3} \cdot \dfrac{n!^3}{2n!}$ Can you simplify now?

This is the expression for $ \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$

You can find the interval of  convergence considering the following : $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right| < 1$.

The last infact is the necessary and sufficient condition for the convergence of the sum.
Once you simplified your expression ( using the hint i gave you) you have to plug it in to the last inequality and solve for $x$.

Comment: I don't follow where (2n+2)(2n+1) came from.

Comment: $(2(n+1))!=(2n+2)!=(2n+2)(2n+1)\cdot ((2n)!)$ can you see it now?

Comment: No I don't see it.

Comment: well we have $(2n+2)!=(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)...(2)(1)$ now i hope you can see that all the terms after $(2n+1)$ are equivalent to the factiorial $(2n)!$ by definition. So you have $(2n+2)(2n+1)\cdot 2n!$. If you still don't see it you should try to think about it a bit harder and ask precisily wich step you didn't understand so i can help $or$ you have troubles with the theory then i suggest to go trough the definitions of factorial etc..